# When using different groups of examinees to answer the same set of items, whether the item parameter should be invariant?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, psychometrics, item-response-theory, social-science, mirt

I am now doing a project to estimate the item parameters from the pharmacotherapy exams. Two groups of students from the same university answer the same set of items. From my understanding, the item parameters should be the same because of IRT model's property. But the results of the estimation are totally different. I am wondering why. Is it because the sample scale is too small (each group only has 80 students).

[image][image]